# Second device doesn't get video call

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox to make a video call from one device to the other.
This is my code on the device making the call:

### On `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.videoChat = [[QBChat instance] createAndRegisterVideoChatInstance];
    self.videoChat.viewToRenderOpponentVideoStream = self.otherUserView;
    self.videoChat.viewToRenderOwnVideoStream = self.selfView;

    QBASessionCreationRequest *extendedAuthRequest = [QBASessionCreationRequest request];
    extendedAuthRequest.userLogin = USERNAME 
    extendedAuthRequest.userPassword = PASSWORD
    [QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self];

}
```

### Session created

```
#pragma mark - QBActionStatusDelegate

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBAAuthSessionCreationResult.class]){
        // Success, You have got User session

        QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *res = (QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *)result;

        QBUUser *currentUser = [QBUUser user];
        currentUser.ID = res.session.userID;
        currentUser.password = PASSWORD

        // set Chat delegate
        [QBChat instance].delegate = self;

        // login to Chat
        [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
    }
}
```

### Logged in to chat

```
(void) chatDidLogin {
    // You have successfully signed in to QuickBlox Chat
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:[QBChat instance] selector:@selector(sendPresence) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

### Making the call:

```
- (IBAction)callUser:(id)sender {


    [QBChat instance].delegate = self;
    [self.videoChat callUser:USERID conferenceType:QBVideoChatConferenceTypeAudioAndVideo];
}
```

### Getting the call

I've checked. The user is logged into the chat, the ID I'm trying to call is correct and the other user is also logged into the chat, but this never gets called:

```
-(void) chatDidReceiveCallRequestFromUser:(NSUInteger)userID withSessionID:(NSString *)_sessionID conferenceType:(enum QBVideoChatConferenceType)conferenceType {
    self.videoChat = [[QBChat instance] createAndRegisterVideoChatInstanceWithSessionID:_sessionID];
    //
    [self.videoChat acceptCallWithOpponentID:userID conferenceType:conferenceType];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Here is the answer, I was creating the `QBVideoChat` object too early. I ended up creating it after I'm logged into the chat

```
-(void) chatDidLogin {
    // You have successfully signed in to QuickBlox Chat
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:[QBChat instance] selector:@selector(sendPresence) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    self.videoChat = [[QBChat instance] createAndRegisterVideoChatInstance];
    self.videoChat.viewToRenderOpponentVideoStream = self.otherUserView;
    self.videoChat.viewToRenderOwnVideoStream = self.selfView;
 }
```